# SSIS and configuration files

Tags: file, ssis, configuration

I have an SSIS package that uses a configuration file which only contains the InitalCatalog and ServerName for an SQL Server database connection. If the configuration file is missing, the SSIS package produces a warning that the file is missing but carries on executing.

If the database connection manager in the package is configured with a different Server Name (ServerName in the configuration file) and Database Name (InitialCatalog in the configuration file), the package will run and use the "wrong" database, i.e. the one in the package's connection manager, not the one in the configuration file.

I have got round this by writing a Script task that checks for the existence of the configuration file and executes the line Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Script task", "Missing Configuration File", String.Empty, 0); if the file is missing. This results in an error being returned to the package and it terminates.

Surely, an SSIS package should terminate if it can't find its configuration file?

Apart from my workaround above, is there any other way to force a package to error and exit if it can't find its configuration file?

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: make the property that it is setting fail if the config file doesn't exist instead of running on the wrong database.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I'm not sure what you mean. Please could you clarify? Thanks